# How to convert UTC to local time zone in PostgreSQL while fetching data from database

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have used all the options to use local time zone instead of UTC but not work properly as my database connection below any body help to solve this.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.POSTGRES_DBNAME, process.env.POSTGRES_USERNAME, process.env.POSTGRES_PASS, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: false,
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
  pool: {
    max: Number(process.env.MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS) || 100,
    min: Number(process.env.MIN_DB_CONNECTIONS) || 50,
  },
  dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: true, // -->Add this line. for reading from database
  },
  timezone: "Asia/Karachi"
});
```

Comment: I don't know about these unspecified nodejs libraries you're using, but in Postgres you can use `my_timestamptz_field AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Karachi'` and it will convert it.

Comment: i am using sequelize